# Angular handling multiple the same subscriptions

Tags: angular

I have an angular app with a component that has 2 modal dialogs: the first for confirming the deletion, the second for confirming cancel and I have subscriptions:

```
this.confirmCancelSubscription = this.interactionService.confirm$.subscribe((confirm: boolean) => {
  console.log(1);
  if (confirm) {
    //some actions
    this.modalRef2.hide();
  }
});

this.confirmDeleteSubscription = this.interactionService.confirm$.subscribe((confirm: boolean) => {
  console.log(2);
  if (confirm) {
    //some actions
    this.modalRef3.hide();
  }
});
```

Into `interaction.service.ts`:

```
private confirmSource = new Subject<boolean>();
confirm$ = this.confirmSource.asObservable();
confirm(confirm: boolean) {
  this.confirmSource.next(confirm);
}
```

But when I click Delete or Cancel on the modal dialog I see in the browser console `1` and `2`.

Is there a way to separate the same subscriptions somehow? Or do I need to create a new method into `interaction.service.ts` for that?

Comment: One way is to emit the relevant information (whether 'delete' or 'cancel') in the notification and perform corresponding action. Also in that case one subscription to the observable should suffice. You could perform both the actions based on the notification within the single subscription.

Comment: Agreed only one subscription is needed with `next()` called with enum or string, to differentiate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` in pipe. This is an example with pure RxJS

```
enum DialogType {
  CONFIRM,
  CANCEL,
}

const confirmSource = new Subject<{ type: DialogType; confirm: boolean }>();
const confirm$ = confirmSource.asObservable();
const confirm = (type: DialogType, confirm: boolean) => {
  confirmSource.next({ type, confirm });
};

confirm$
  .pipe(filter((dialog) => dialog.type === DialogType.CANCEL))
  .subscribe((dialog) => {
    console.log('Cancel dialog with', dialog.confirm);
  });

confirm$
  .pipe(filter((dialog) => dialog.type === DialogType.CONFIRM))
  .subscribe((dialog) => {
    console.log('Confirm dialog with', dialog.confirm);
  });

console.log('Confirming true');
confirm(DialogType.CONFIRM, true);

console.log('Confirming false');
confirm(DialogType.CONFIRM, false);

console.log('Canceling false');
confirm(DialogType.CANCEL, false);

console.log('Canceling true');
confirm(DialogType.CANCEL, true);
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-q62abr?file=index.ts)

## Another option - separate everything

```
const confirmSource = new Subject<boolean>();
const cancelSource = new Subject<boolean>();
const confirm$ = confirmSource.asObservable();
const cancel$ = cancelSource.asObservable();

const confirm = (confirm: boolean) => {
  confirmSource.next(confirm);
};

const cancel = (confirm: boolean) => {
  cancelSource.next(confirm);
};

cancel$.subscribe((confirm) => {
  console.log('Cancel dialog with', confirm);
});

confirm$.subscribe((confirm) => {
  console.log('Confirm dialog with', confirm);
});

console.log('Confirming true');
confirm(true);

console.log('Confirming false');
confirm(false);

console.log('Canceling false');
cancel(false);

console.log('Canceling true');
cancel(true);
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-urg2rw?file=index.ts)

Comment: not sure it's what I want. I have one modal for remove item and one modal for discard changes and they are both can return true or false.

Comment: This solution doesn't really fulfill the question's requirement. Also, it subscribes the same observable twice, which is more than anti best practice.

Comment: I've modified answer

Comment: @sandrooco I'm not sure why subscribing multiple times would be a bad practice. It's completely reasonable if you need it in different locations, which me might since we don't have enough context.

Comment: @BojanKogoj the first option with `filter` pipe and DialogType enum works for me, thanks! The second option also works I think but not sure it's good way to create multiple subscriptions / duplicates of code.

Comment: Fair enough, I misread your solution (thought the subscribtions would be in the same component.)